# Forms designer : How to make a control ignore a flowlayoutpanel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms-designer, flowlayoutpanel

When using the forms designer I ran into a small problem (I could solve this with code but I wondered if there's an easy way.)

I have a `flowlayoutpanel` and when I drag a new control on it (for example a `label`) it will give it a position in the `flowlayoutpanel` and I am unable to move it other then changing the order with other controls.

**The question : Is there a way to add a control on top of a `flowlayoutpanel` ?(So ignoring the auto arrangement.)**

Extra info : The reason I want to know this is because I am using the `height` of the `flowlayoutpanel` for the creating other forms and I rather keep that code as is.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but WPF is a somewhat newer technology by Microsoft (2008), and it is more powerful/flexible as far as layout goes. If you can't find an answer and continue to fight with Windows Forms, you might consider the jump to WPF as an alternate technology.

Comment: @LearningMode Ha, Didn't even know that tag existed. Thnx for the edit :)

Comment: @NexTerren Yes I am aware :) I just want to get to learn C# and its basics a bit and am having quite a bit of fun with it. (Haven't had any major blockers for what I wanted to achieve) But I do want to try out WPF later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is use arrow keys. Place your control out side `flowlayoutpanel` then use these keys to move it to top of `flowlayoutpanel`.

You can combine it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, which some times turn out very helpful because it will move you control to the places which one of your control borders is on samle line with one of other controls.

One other way, you can set `Location` for control directly, if you know the exactly where the control should being add.

Comment: This worked perfectly! It's a bit slow but hey saves me from editing like 20 lines of code, Thanks!

Comment: @R593B One other way, you can set `Location` for control directly, if you know the exactly where the control should being add.

Comment: Ahh yes but then you would have to use  `BringToFront` as well.  (Had to do this for the label too but was pretty easy using the document outline)